# GoogleApiClient not connected if used from fragment

Tags: android, google-signin

I discovered a strange behaviour today.

I have my activity which connects to the GoogleApiClient in onStart() and disconnects in the onStop()

The activity uses a GridViewPager to show my fragments. To send messages through the Data Layer i use a callback interface between activity and fragment.

If i call sendMessage() from a button within the Activity layout it works fine. If sendMessage() is executed by the fragment using the callback interface sendMessage() shows the "not connected" Toast.

In both ways the same method in the Activity is called so how is it possible that it behaves different ?

I should mention that the problem only occours after the application is restarted for the first time.

Activity

```
public class WearPlex extends WearableActivity implements
    NavigationRemoteCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private List<Node> nodeList = new ArrayList<Node>();
private List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wear_plex);
    setAmbientEnabled();

    fragmentList.add(NavigationRemoteFragment.getInstance(this));

    GridViewPager mGridPager = (GridViewPager)findViewById(R.id.gridViewPager);
    mGridPager.setAdapter(new MainGridPageAdapter(getFragmentManager(), fragmentList));

    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    googleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    googleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    nodeList.clear();
    Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(googleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult nodes) {
            for (Node node : nodes.getNodes()) nodeList.add(node);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void navigationRemoteSendCommand(String commandPath) {
    sendMessage(commandPath, null);
}

public void debugOnClick(View view) {
    sendMessage("/debug", null);
}

public void sendMessage(String path, byte[] data) {
    if (googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.size(); i++) {
            if (nodeList.get(i).isNearby()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Send message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(googleApiClient, nodeList.get(i).getId(), path, data);
            }
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Not connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Connection failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Fragment

```
public class NavigationRemoteFragment extends Fragment {

private static NavigationRemoteFragment navigationRemoteFragment = null;

private NavigationRemoteCallbacks callbackHandler = null;

private ImageButton navBtnCenter;

public static NavigationRemoteFragment getInstance(NavigationRemoteCallbacks handler) {
    if (navigationRemoteFragment == null) {
        navigationRemoteFragment = new NavigationRemoteFragment();
        navigationRemoteFragment.callbackHandler = handler;
    }

    return navigationRemoteFragment;
}

public NavigationRemoteFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_remote, container, false);

    navBtnCenter = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.navBtnCenter);

    navBtnCenter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            callbackHandler.navigationRemoteSendCommand("/debug");
        }
    });

    return v;
}
```

}

Callback interface

```
public interface NavigationRemoteCallbacks {
    public void navigationRemoteSendCommand(String commandPath);
}
```

EDIT 1 code for MainGridPageAdapter

```
public class MainGridPageAdapter extends FragmentGridPagerAdapter {

private List<Fragment> fragmentList = null;

public MainGridPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragmentList) {
    super(fm);
    this.fragmentList = fragmentList;
}

@Override
public Fragment getFragment(int i, int i1) {
    if (i1 < fragmentList.size()) return fragmentList.get(i1);
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return 1;
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount(int i) {
    return fragmentList.size();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show the code for `MainGridPageAdapter` so I don't know how it is managing fragments.  You mention that the problem occurs after a restart.  Looking at the code in `WearPlex.onCreate()`, I suspect that the problem is caused fragments that are holding a reference to an old, destroyed instance of the activity.

A poorly documented behavior of `FragmentManager` is that it saves its state across restarts. This is often overlooked, resulting in duplicate fragment instances after a restart.  The correct pattern for managing fragment creation in the `onCreate()` method of the host activity is:

```
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // Not a restart
        // Create a new instance of the fragment
        // Add it to the fragment manager
    } else {
        // Restart
        // The fragment manager has saved and restored the fragment instances
        // Use findFragmentById() to get the fragment if you need it
    }
```

You are not using `savedInstanceState` in `onCreate()` to test for restart.  Are you seeing more fragments than you expect after restart?  If so, the original fragments are holding a reference to the old activity, which was stopped, and has a disconnected GoogleApiClient. If the NavBtn of one of those fragments is clicked, you will see the "not connected" toast.

**Update**

The problem is caused by the way you are creating new instances of `NavigationRemoteFragment`, specifically the use of **static** member `navigationRemoteFragment`.  After a restart, when the activity is recreated, the code calls `NavigationRemoteFragment.getInstance(this)`.  `getInstance()` finds `navigationRemoteFragment` not null because it is static, and does not create a new fragment.  The fragment returned is the old one, which holds a reference to the old activity, which has been stopped and has a disconnected `GoogleApiClient`.

This could be confirmed by using the [isDestroyed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isDestroyed()) method and adding a some debug logging:

```
@Override
public void navigationRemoteSendCommand(String commandPath) {
    if (isDestroyed()) {
        Log.w("TEST", "This is an old instance of the activity");
    }
    sendMessage(commandPath, null);
}
```

Comment: First of alls thanks for the fast response. I have attached the `MainGridPageAdapter` in the first post. If i call `getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()` from within `onCreate()` it is allways `0` after restarting the application. I dont think there are multiple instances of a fragment within the fragment manager because the GridViewPager shows only a single fragment.